# Reading data from website and trying to get accented characters

Tags: python, utf-8

So I am reading a json off of a website and this is part of my output

```
{"objects": [{"first_name": "Pascale", "last_name": "D\u00e9ry",...
```

In searching around I see that the \u00e9 is a unicode character corresponding to é.  Fine, I get that.  When trying to solve it, however, I thought that I was supposed to use .encode() when reading the data from the website, like so:

```
import urllib

i=0
j=250

while i<2000:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(r"https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=250&offset={}".format(i)) as url:
        with open(r"F:\electoral_map\candidates_python\candidates{0}_to_{1}.js".format(i,j), "wb+") as f:
            f.write(url.read().encode('utf-8'))
    i+=250
    j=i+250

print("all done")
```

But then I just get the error

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Am I getting this backwards? I also tried .decode('utf-8') but that also doesn't work. (Get TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface)

I should mention that I am using Python 3.

Comment: Can you show a full traceback? Because if you `encode` a string in Python 3, you should get a `bytes` instance, rather than the `str` instance the error message is referring to.

Comment: Are you intending to store the JSON string in the file? If so, you should expect that it will have the unicode escape in your file. Are do you intend to interpret the JSON and store the resulting data?

Comment: I intend to store the json in a file because I have downloaded someone else's script that will convert it into a csv once it has been downloaded and stored.  That script fails because it is encountering this characters so I thought that it was because I wasn't downloading them properly.

Comment: Nope, you are downloading it perfectly. You can confirm this by viewing that page in a web browser and noticing that the data itself has the unicode escape. The problem you are having lies in the script that converts it to csv.

Comment: Damn, I was hoping it wouldn't come to that because that script is waaaaaaaaaay over my head. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try the program I posted below. Hopefully it will be easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 0):

If your real goal is to store the data in a spreadsheet, try this program:

```
import requests
import csv
import json

base_url="https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=250&offset={}"
#base_filename=r"F:\electoral_map\candidates_python\candidates{0}_to_{1}.csv"
base_filename=r"candidates{0}_to_{1}.csv"
keys = [
    'name',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'election_name',
    'elected_office',
    'district_name',
    'email',
    'incumbent',
    'party_name',
    'personal_url',
    'photo_url',
    'source_url',
    'url',
]

for i in range(0, 2000, 250):
    url = base_url.format(i)
    filename=base_filename.format(i, i+250)
    data = requests.get(url)
    data = data.text
    data = json.loads(data)
    data = data['objects']

    with open(filename, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, keys, extrasaction='ignore')
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows(data)
```

Note: this program requires Python3. If you are using Python2, let me know, I'll try to give you a version that works there.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `decode()` would be the appropriate thing to do to the downloaded JSON string.

Consider this simplified example which will download the JSON for a single candidate by specifying `limit=1&offset=0` in the URL:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> url = urlopen('https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1&offset=0')
>>> content = url.read()
>>> print(type(content))
<class 'bytes'>
>>> print(url.getheader('Content-Type'))
application/json; charset=utf-8
>>> content
b'{"objects": [{"first_name": "Pascale", "last_name": "D\\u00e9ry", "election_name": "House of Commons", "name": "Pascale D\\u00e9ry", "elected_office": "candidate", "url": "", "gender": "", "extra": {}, "related": {"boundary_url": "/boundaries/federal-electoral-districts-next-election/24025/", "election_url": "/elections/house-of-commons/"}, "source_url": "http://www.conservative.ca/?member=candidates", "offices": [], "party_name": "Conservative", "incumbent": null, "district_name": "Drummond", "email": "", "personal_url": "http://www.conservative.ca/team/member/?fname=Pascale&lname=D\\u00e9ry&type=candidates", "photo_url": "http://www.conservative.ca/media/team/Pascale-Dery.jpg"}], "meta": {"next": "/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1&offset=1", "total_count": 1129, "previous": null, "limit": 1, "offset": 0}}'
```

From this we see that the content is of type bytes, i.e. a byte string. Byte strings do not have an `encode()` method; they are presumed to already be in *some* encoding, and can only be decoded to unicode using the correct encoding. In this case the data is UTF-8 encoded JSON as indicated by the `Content-Type` header.

There are a number of things that you can do here:

- Open the output file in binary mode and simply write the JSON string
  as is to the file. Because the incoming data is UTF-8 encoded this
  will result in a UTF-8 encoded JSON file, which is probably what the
  CSV converter expects:

  ```
  with open('output.json', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(content)
  ```
- Open the output file in text mode using an encoding supported by the
  CSV converter, decode the incoming JSON string from UTF-8 into a text
  string (unicode), and write the decoded string to the file:

  ```
  with open('output.json', 'w', encoding='iso-8859-1') as f:
      f.write(content.decode('utf-8'))
  ```

  Here I chose the iso-8859-1 encoding as an example, you could also choose ASCII. Note that if the encoding is UTF-8 this would decode and then re-encode the data as UTF-8, so you might just as well write the data as is in the first place.
- Another option, and the one that I'd recommend, is to decode the incoming data using a JSON decoder and then write it out to a file using your preferred encoding. This has the advantage of ensuring that the incoming data is in fact JSON and lets you pick up any errors prior to handing off to the CSV converter:

  ```
  import json
  with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
      data = json.loads(content.decode('utf8'))
      json.dump(data, f)
  ```

---

You might actually find it easier to use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module. It has built-in JSON parsing, and character decoding:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://represent.opennorth.ca/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1&offset=0')
>>> type(r.text)
>>> type(r.content)
>>> data = r.json()
>>> data
{'objects': [{'first_name': 'Pascale', 'extra': {}, 'url': '', 'last_name': 'Déry', 'district_name': 'Drummond', 'incumbent': None, 'offices': [], 'gender': '', 'personal_url': 'http://www.conservative.ca/team/member/?fname=Pascale&lname=Déry&type=candidates', 'elected_office': 'candidate', 'party_name': 'Conservative', 'source_url': 'http://www.conservative.ca/?member=candidates', 'election_name': 'House of Commons', 'email': '', 'name': 'Pascale Déry', 'photo_url': 'http://www.conservative.ca/media/team/Pascale-Dery.jpg', 'related': {'boundary_url': '/boundaries/federal-electoral-districts-next-election/24025/', 'election_url': '/elections/house-of-commons/'}}], 'meta': {'total_count': 1129, 'limit': 1, 'next': '/candidates/house-of-commons/?limit=1&offset=1', 'previous': None, 'offset': 0}}
```

Here `r.content` is the raw content as downloaded in whatever encoding the server sent the data. `r.text` is that same raw content decoded into a unicode string. And `r.json()` gives you the parsed JSON data as a dictionary. Writing it out to a file is then as simple as:

```
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(r.json(), f)
```